# How can I replace line #6 in a text file in a bash script?

Tags: bash, text, shell-scripting

I have a text file that is generated by 3rd-party software as part of a build process. I want to replace one specific line - in my case, line 6. How can I do this in my bash script?

I suspect sed is my friend here but I'm now stumped.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6 if that's important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `sed "6s/old/new/g" file.txt`

Comment: If you don't care what you're replacing on line six, you can use `sed "6s/.*/new/" file.txt` too.